# gravity form create post after add entry via web api

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

we develop mobile app for a website that have gravity form and we can make entry via [web api](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/web-api/) of gravity form, but in website when submit the form it's create new post automatically because form have some post fields and when we add new entry via web api it just add entry not post.
how can we define that this entry must be saved to post via gravity forms web api?

Update:

gravity form can create post via it forms if that form have post fields. [read more](https://gravitywiz.com/use-gravity-forms-to-create-user-submitted-posts/)

and this functionality is just for submission form so you can't access it via web api.

for do this you must add it manually

complete example that must be placed at `themes/YOUR_THEME/functions.php`:

```
$api_key = 'your_public_key';
  $private_key = 'your_private_key';

  //set route
  $route = 'entries'; // or 'forms/{formID}/entries'

  //creating request URL
  $expires = strtotime( '+1 day' );
  $string_to_sign = sprintf( '%s:%s:%s:%s', $api_key, 'POST', $route, $expires );
  $sig = calculate_signature( $string_to_sign, $private_key );
  $url = 'http://your_domain.com/gravityformsapi/' . $route . '?api_key=' . $api_key . '&signature=' . $sig . '&expires=' . $expires;

if(isset($_POST)){
  $body = [
    [
      "form_id"=> "1", // if $route is just 'entries'
      '1' => "Post Title" ,
      '2'  => "Post Content"

    ]
    //,[ another entry ]
  ];

  $response = wp_remote_post($url,['body'=>json_encode($body)]);
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   wp_send_json_error($response->get_error_message());
} else {
   $body = json_decode($response['body'],true);
   if($body['status'] === 201){
   foreach($body['response'] as $entry_id){ //get each entry ID
      $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );
      if(!is_wp_error($entry)){
         $form = GFAPI::get_form( rgar($entry,'form_id') );
         if($form)
           GFCommon::create_post( $form, $entry); //Finally add Post.
         else
           wp_send_json_error("can not find entry form.");
      }else
         wp_send_json_error($entry->get_error_message());
   }
   wp_send_json_success("Success!");
   }else{
     wp_send_json_error($body);
   }
}

}else
   wp_send_json_error("request body invalid");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$api_key = 'your_public_key';
  $private_key = 'your_private_key';

  //set route
  $route = 'entries'; // or 'forms/{formID}/entries'

  //creating request URL
  $expires = strtotime( '+1 day' );
  $string_to_sign = sprintf( '%s:%s:%s:%s', $api_key, 'POST', $route, $expires );
  $sig = calculate_signature( $string_to_sign, $private_key );
  $url = 'http://your_domain.com/gravityformsapi/' . $route . '?api_key=' . $api_key . '&signature=' . $sig . '&expires=' . $expires;

if(isset($_POST)){
  $body = [
    [
      "form_id"=> "1", // if $route is just 'entries'
      '1' => "Post Title" ,
      '2'  => "Post Content"

    ]
    //,[ another entry ]
  ];

  $response = wp_remote_post($url,['body'=>json_encode($body)]);
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   wp_send_json_error($response->get_error_message());
} else {
   $body = json_decode($response['body'],true);
   if($body['status'] === 201){
   foreach($body['response'] as $entry_id){ //get each entry ID
      $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );
      if(!is_wp_error($entry)){
         $form = GFAPI::get_form( rgar($entry,'form_id') );
         if($form)
           GFCommon::create_post( $form, $entry); //Finally add Post.
         else
           wp_send_json_error("can not find entry form.");
      }else
         wp_send_json_error($entry->get_error_message());
   }
   wp_send_json_success("Success!");
   }else{
     wp_send_json_error($body);
   }
}

}else
   wp_send_json_error("request body invalid");
```